# Pass data to footer with wkhtmltopdf in Go lang

Tags: go, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am using go-wkhtmltopdf package to generate PDF with go lang. I am using below code to display a footer on every page in the PDF. I want to pass some dynamic data to the footer to display the same. I am not finding any way to do so. Please help

```
"bytes"
"encoding/base64"
"fmt"
htmlTemplate "html/template"
"path"
"strings"
textTemplate "text/template"
wkhtml "github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf"

pdfg, err := wkhtml.NewPDFGenerator()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
page := wkhtml.NewPageReader(strings.NewReader(util.FilterSmartQuotesEtc(html)))
page.FooterHTML.Set("templates/footer.html")
pdfg.AddPage(page)
err = pdfg.Create()
```

templates/footer.html is the footer file where I want to pass the data. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Show your imports - there appear to be multiple packages that do something like  this

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt updated the question to include imports.

Comment: I didn't understand exactly. Are you trying adding data to the footer within your program ? Then auto set to pdf ?

Comment: @BrokenArmor I have an ID to be printed in the footer which is dynamic and I should be able to pass it to the footer to display it. The code in my question is setting a footer HTML file for the PDF document which gets printed correctly at the bottom of every page in the PDF document. I need a way to print an ID on the footer as I said above.

Answer (score 2):

"Dynamic data" in HTML code suggests using [HTLM templates](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template) (data-driven templates for generating HTML output safe against code injection)

You can use the template [ParseFiles()](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template#ParseFiles) to get said template from your footer, and inject your dynamic data. (See for instance "[Golang HTML Template `ParseFiles` and `Execute`](https://dev.to/divshekhar/golang-html-template-parsefiles-and-execute-2mh8)" as an example)

> I have an ID to be printed in the footer which is dynamic and I should be able to pass it to the footer to display it.

Assuming you have a struct to hold your dynamic data, for instance:

```golang
type FooterData struct {
    ID string
}
```

And assuming a (very) simple template for your `templates/footer.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        /* Your footer styles */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        ID: {{.ID}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can create a function to save the rendered HTML to a temporary file and return the file path (to be used as URL for `page.FooterHTML.Set(footerHTML)`):

```golang
import (
    "io/ioutil"
    //...
)

func renderFooterHTML(templatePath string, data *FooterData) (string, error) {
    tmpl, err := htmlTemplate.ParseFiles(templatePath)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    err = tmpl.Execute(&buf, data)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    // Save the rendered HTML to a temporary file
    tmpFile, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "footer-*.html")
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    if _, err := tmpFile.Write(buf.Bytes()); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    if err := tmpFile.Close(); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return tmpFile.Name(), nil
}
```

And then modify your existing code to use the rendered footer HTML:

```golang
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    htmlTemplate "html/template"
    "path"
    "strings"
    textTemplate "text/template"
    wkhtml "github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf"
)

// ...

pdfg, err := wkhtml.NewPDFGenerator()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

page := wkhtml.NewPageReader(strings.NewReader(util.FilterSmartQuotesEtc(html)))

// Render the footer HTML with your dynamic data
footerData := &FooterData{
    ID: "Your dynamic ID here",
}
footerFilePath, err := renderFooterHTML("templates/footer.html", footerData)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

// Use the rendered footer HTML file
page.FooterHTML.Set(footerFilePath)

pdfg.AddPage(page)
err = pdfg.Create()

//...

// Delete the temporary footer file when you're done with it
os.Remove(footerFilePath)
```

Do replace the string in `ID: "Your dynamic ID here"` with your actual dynamic ID value.

Comment: There is no `SetContent` method on `page.FooterHTML`, there is `Set` method on it. Also we need put the location of the footer html as argument to it, instead of whole modified footer as string. Because I had got error while running this code `Error: --footer-html should be a URL and not a string containing HTML code.
Exit with code 1, due to unknown error.` To fix this we need convert the updated footer html string to again html. Then call `Set` method with updated footer html location `page.FooterHTML.Set("templates/footer.html")`

Comment: @BrokenArmor I see: [`looksLikeHtmlAndNotAUrl`](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/blob/c477d24eb337f02178e36e1dd351b74290818d7c/src/lib/pdfconverter.cc#L182-L183) prevents to set the footer content directly. 

Thank you for your feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly. I will follow up tomorrow morning.